# Java how can i get variables inside a method and the reverse

Tags: java, variables, methods

Could some one tell me how can i get variable inside methods and the reverse.
Something like:
i want to use variable y inside that method func, and get that x from that method func and use it inside main.

```
class test{
int y = 4;

void func(){
int x = 3;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
// take x inside main
}}
```

Comment: Change signature of func and make it return int

Comment: You can use x outside func , because that's a local attribute of function . If you want to use in the main function .Make it static variable of the class.

Comment: And make func static or create instance of class test then call func that return x

Answer (score 1):

You can always use class variable inside methods. To use x of func() inside main() method, you can return it from func() or save it into some class variable

```
class TestClass {
int y = 4;
int x = 0;

//func returning x
int func1() {
    int x = y;
    return x;
}

//func storing it to class variable
void func2() {
    this.x = 3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass t = new TestClass();
    int xOfFunc = t.func1();

    t.func2();
    System.out.println("x Of Func :: " + xOfFunc + "\n class variable x :: " + t.x);
    }
}
```

output :

```
x Of Func :: 4 
class variable x :: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class test{
 int y = 4;

 int func(){
  int x = 3;
  return x;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   test obj = new test();
   int x = obj.func();
  }
}
```

or you can make func() method static and you will be able to call this method without creating an object of class:

```
class test{
 int y = 4;

 static int func(){
  int x = 3;
  return x;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

   int x = func();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class test{
    int y = 4;
    int x;

    void func(){
       int x = 3;
       this.x = 3; //make it usable from the class
    }
}
```

y should be accessible inside the function. If the function uses a variable y by itself you can use this.y to access the variable.

Make it static like this allows you to access it everywhere by calling test.y.

```
class test{
    public static int y = 4;

    void func(){
       int x = 3;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this in main.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int value = test.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   class Main {
    public int y= 4;
    int func(){
    return 4;
    }
    public static void main(String... args){
    Main m = new Main();
    int x = m.func();
    int y = m.y;

}
}
```